# Using ng-controller directive on dom element calls controller 3 times Why?

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-controller directive on dom element to specify the controller. But every time when the controller is initialized it is called 3 times consecutively.

Also for every controller for every directive it is called 3 times.

It would be great if anyone can tell me ht exact reason why this is happening?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue myself a while ago. Some relevant questions for you: what version of AngularJS? Is your `ng-controller` directive inside something that uses transclusion (e.g. an `ng-view`)?

In some cases I just used [`_.debounce()`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) or [`_.throttle()`](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) to solve the problem. Not a great solution, though.

Comment: Angular Version 1.2.26

Comment: Yes my controller is in the ui-view and on page refresh it is called thrice.

 <div id="ui-view" class="container-fluid" style="width:1500px; overflow-x:auto" ui-view data-tmpl-url="@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["templateUrl"]">

        @RenderBody()

    </div>

This is will render the partial into body.

This is the ng-if that I placed on dashboard if user role is clietn the load client dashboard.
<div ng-if="userRole === 'Client'" ng-include="'/Views/Templates/Client/ClientDashboard.html'" ng-controller="SharedDashboardCtrl"></div>

But SharedDashboardCtrl is called 3 times.

Comment: Better edit you question and write down your code in format. @user3351159